# Azure Function not connecting to mysql after deploy NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I've made a simple Azure function that when executed will run an insert query to a MySQL database. The MySQL database lives on a HostGator server (shared plan). The Azure function I wrote is able to insert to the DB table as expected when running locally, but after I deploy to Azure the function appears to run fine, but then no new records show in the database table.

Below is the function code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '*****************',
        user: '*************',
        password: '*************',
        database: '***************'
    });

    connection.connect();

    const insertQuery = `INSERT into emails (email_address, first_name, last_name, preferred_game, date_joined) VALUES ('bob@example.com', 'Bob', 'Jones', 'both', NOW());`;
    await connection.query(insertQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
      });

    connection.end();
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: '200'
    };
}
```

The strange thing is that I don't see any errors in the logs anywhere, so it appears to work, but when I look in the DB no new records have been inserted. I thought at first it might be an IP whitelist issue, but after adding the Azure Function App IP it still failed to insert a record to the DB (Virtual IP as shown under app properties in the Azure portal).

I can't think of why else this wouldn't be able to insert records to the DB from the deployed Azure function.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `context.log` to trace if the function is actually running firstly and then if it is and the connection is a problem, there'll be an error message that may help

Comment: Hello John! How did you deploy the function, was it a pure Zip-deploy or did you run it through a pipeline? What I'm thinking about is the package mysql and if it is installed or not.

Comment: I do have some context.logs in there, I just took them out when I pasted the code here. I think it was a zip deploy. I deployed it from VS Code using the Azure add-on for functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've whitelisted, sounds like the "Inbound" IP address. It may be because you haven't whitelisted your "outbound" IP address(es).

Get the outbound IPs with `az CLI`

`az functionapp show --resource-group <GROUP_NAME> --name <APP_NAME> --query outboundIpAddresses --output tsv`

Or get the outbound IPs in the portal properties (where you found Virtual IP).

[image]

See here for [more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=azurecli#find-outbound-ip-addresses)